# C++ dynamic memory allocation not working as expected

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to wrap my head around why this works. As far as I understand when i dynamically allocate 3 ints it shouldn't let me add more after index 2 but the code below compiles and runs perfectly well. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int* nums = new int[3];
    nums[0] = 5;
    nums[1] = 6;
    nums[2] = 5;

    nums[3] = 7;
    nums[4] = 8;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        std::cout << nums[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete nums;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. Don't do this

Comment: Use std::vector instead of new. Then you wouldn’t have used the wrong delete.

Comment: C/C++ does not enforce bounds checking, you're accessing an undefined chunk of memory that might or might not hold something else.  Try this using a struct with  {  int a[3], b[3] } and notice that &a[4] might have the same address as &b[1]

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why
Possibly duplicate of this question.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks guys for the quick reply!

Comment: @cainsr2 -- Think of it this way -- if you had your driver's license suspended, does that mean you can't get into a car and drive it, possibly for hundreds of miles without being stopped once by a policeman?  Of course you can.  Does it mean it is legal for you to do so? Of course it isn't legal.  C++ works in this fashion -- you're "allowed" to do things that are undefined, and you may have nothing go wrong, or your whole program may collapse.

Comment: By the way, `delete nums;` should be `delete[] nums;`.

Comment: @manni66 The availability of better options like `std::vector` is not a valid excuse for not understanding which delete operator to use. It's still an important concept to understand. Using vector doesn't help OP understand that.

Comment: @MillieSmith how do you know that the concept is not understood?

Comment: @manni66 I'm guessing I suppose based on the fact that OP doesn't know buffer overflows will compile but are undefined behavior. Which I think is a pretty reasonable guess.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you're accessing additional memory and assigning values to it on lines:

```
nums[3] = 7;
nums[4] = 8;
```

Since you allocated `3` slots for your array it allocated memory required, but when you're using `pointers` you're accessing the memory location directly so you can freely jump out of your array memory space and venture into `unknown` memory.

This is **VERY BAD** practice as you don't know what's located on those memory slots.

Answer (score -1):

C++ is an unsafe language. If you allocate 3 `int`s on the heap, you have to make sure that you do not later try to write to where there would be a 4th or 5th `int`. C++ will allow you write there even though it's a bad idea.

One solution to this problem is to almost never use the pointers built into the language. You can make, or use someone else's, pointer class. It should be a template class, that way you can make a pointer to anything: `pntr<int>`, `pntr<Car>`,`pntr<ostream>`, `pntr<string>`, etc...

Overload:

- `operator new[]`
- the deference operator,
- operator bracket-bracket
- etc...

Your pointer class can throw an error if you try to write to  where you are not supposed to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pntr.h"

int main() {
    pntr<int> nums = new int[3];
    nums[0] = 5;
    nums[1] = 6;
    nums[2] = 5;    
    nums[3] = 7; // THROWS AN ERROR
    nums[4] = 8; 

    delete nums;

    return 0;
}
```